# Trouble retrieving Page values in save event

Tags: 2013-sp1, event-system

I am trying to do some validation on saving a page. Part of this involves checking the page template. When I try to read it, however, I get the default value for the page template. This is even after changing it.

In this example item.PageTemplate.Title shows "Default Page Template" even though I have selected "Specific Page Template".

```
namespace Tridion.EventSystem.Extensions.OnSaveValidation
{
    [TcmExtension("Check Items On Save")]
    public class CheckItemsOnSave : TcmExtension
    {

        public CheckItemsOnSave()
        {
            EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, SaveEventArgs>(HandlerForSavePage, EventPhases.Initiated);
        }

        public void HandlerForSavePage(Page item, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
        {
            if (item.PageTemplate.Title != "Specific Page Template")
            {
                throw new Exception("Incorrect Page Template: " + item.PageTemplate.Title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the `Initiated` event phase, so the data for the page hasn't been changed by Tridion yet. Change your subscription to hook into the `EventPhases.Processed` phase and you should see the updated information but still have the opportunity to throw an exception and reject the change.